# Azure Custom Vision Project

Tags: azure, microsoft-custom-vision

I am creating an azure custom vision project in python, every time i run the code, it creates new projects and my project count keeps increasing.

How can i delete an existing project before creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to want to check which projects you have, which you can check with the GetProjects API. This will give you have a list of projects with their project ids. Once you have project ids for the projects you want to delete, then you can just call the DeleteProject API, passing in the project id. You can also managed you projects via the Custom Vision Service portal at [www.customvision.ai](http://www.customvision.ai), just be sure to sign in with your account.